# Why the github icon doesn't show in the navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, favicon

How should I fix this so that the github icon shows in the navbar?

```
<a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-0" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github">Github</i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-0" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github">Github</i></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `font-awesome.min.css` to your project?

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhz8nr9b/)

Comment: hey I can't understand what's the difference between your code and mine? <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-0" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github">Github</i></a>

Comment: Check <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> in Your Code, I think this code is missing